# Source Ordering using Foundation and PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, zurb-foundation

I have hit a wall trying to do some source ordering in Zurb's Foundation 4, the problem lies in my PHP logic though. I'm currently developing a CMS and what the developer can do is edit the number of columns and the column's widths (spans), so lets say he created 3 columns with the next spans = 1, 3 and 8:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [span] => 1
            [position] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [span] => 3
            [position] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
       (
           [span] => 8
           [position] => 2
       )

)
```

The rendered markup would be:

```
<div class="column small-1"></div>
<div class="column small-3"></div>
<div class="column small-8"></div>
```

So in this case the main content will be in the larger column, so what I did is reordered them with PHP so that they are ordered from large to smallest (so that the main content shows up first):

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [span] => 8
            [position] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [span] => 3
            [position] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
       (
            [span] => 1
            [position] => 0
       )

)
```

The rendered markup would be:

```
<div class="column small-8"></div>
<div class="column small-3"></div>
<div class="column small-1"></div>
```

What I need to know is how to add the corresonding push/pull classes automatically to get the result as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [span] => 8
            [position] => 2
            [push] => 4
            [pull] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [span] => 3
            [position] => 1
            [push] => 0
            [pull] => 7
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
       (
            [span] => 1
            [position] => 0
            [push] => 0
            [pull] => 11
       )

)
```

The resulting markup should be:

```
<div class="column small-8 push-4"></div>
<div class="column small-3 pull-7"></div>
<div class="column small-1 pull-11"></div>
```

I have made a function that does this, but its not giving me the right solution, and I think its too complicated:

```
/**
 * Reorders the columns so that they are exactly like the design's order, because we  are ordering the columns from largest to smallest
 * hoping that the largest means more important content than the smallest, so we need a way to return to the original order
 * @param $columns - The column array
 * @param $col - the current column
 * @param $key - current column key
 * @return array
 */
private function source_ordering($columns, $col, $key)
{

    $ordering = array();
    $ordering['pull'] = 0;
    $ordering['push'] = 0;
    $total_spans = 0;

    //How many positions to loop back/forth in the array
    $position_key = $col->position - $key;

    print_r('-------');

    //Push column
    if ($col->position > $key) {

        //Loop forth in the array and add all the column "spans"
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= $position_key) {
            $total_spans += $columns[$key + $i]->span;
            $i++;
        }

        $ordering['push'] = $col->push = $total_spans;

    }

    //Position hasn't changed - Pull?
    else if ($position_key === 0) {

        var_dump($key);

        $pos = $key - 1;
        while ($pos >= 0) {

            print_r($columns[$pos]);

            //Is the previous column pushed or pulled?
            if ($columns[$pos]->push) {
                $ordering['pull'] -= $columns[$pos]->span;
            } else {
                $ordering['pull'] += $columns[$pos]->span;
            }

            $ordering['pull'] = abs($ordering['pull']);

            $pos--;
        }

    }

    //Pull column
    else {

        //Make it positive (easier to calculate)
        $position_key = abs($position_key);

        //Loop forth in the array and add all the column "spans"
        $i = 1;
        while ($i <= $position_key) {
            $total_spans += $columns[$key - $i]->span;
            $i++;
        }

        $ordering['pull'] = $col->pull = $total_spans;

    }

    return $ordering;

}
```

This function is called over each of the columns array:

```
foreach ($columns as $col_key => $col)
{
    $ordering = $this->source_ordering($columns, $col, $col_key);
    $col->pull = $ordering['pull'];
    $col->push = $ordering['push'];
}
```

Keep in mind that the developer can create 1,2,3 or more columns not only 3 as the example I posted.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Short answer: maths, long answer: pain in the butt.

Comment: Well, looks like I will have to go with the "maths" and "pain in the butt" solution lol. Seems like its pretty complex, I was hoping for some other points of view to the problem.

Comment: I'll give this a crack tomorrow as im looking at creating something similar in the near future!